# *Methods* calling a boolean

Tags: java

how can I call a true or false value created with my "public boolean equals method" in a later method "public static void main(String[] args)"?

```
public Car(String color, double insurance)
{
    this.color = color;
    this.insurance = insurance;
}

public boolean equals(Car other)
{   

    if (this.color.equals(other.color) && this.insurance.equals(other.insurance))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get error: cannot invoke equals(double) on the primitive type double

Comment: (1) `equals(Car other)` belongs to `Car` class which means you can invoke them on Car instances like `carInstance.euqlas()` (2) If you want to override already existing `equals` method then you need to declare it using `equals(Object other)` not `equals(Car other)`.

Comment: `if (c1.equals(c2))` -- but your equals method is broken. It should take an Object parameter, not a Car parameter.

Comment: This code is very odd. I'm struggling to understand what you're going for. The whole body of equals should just be `this.color.equals(other.color) && this.insurance.equals(other.insurance;`, and you never even call `equals`. Also, writing `if(true)` is completely useless.

Comment: This question isn't really a duplicate of the one provided... The problem is that the user is calling `.equals(..)` on a `double`. The user should instead use `this.insurance == other.insurance`

Comment: @lucasvw There are at least three problems here, and they have mostly been covered in the comments now. I'll add you should use `@Override` to catch the method signature mismatch.

Comment: @Deebee: then sorry to say but your teacher may be a bit confused on Java standards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call method here:

```
Car car1;

...
     if(equals(car1)){
...
}
```